# Call a getter function with its name in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

When I create a class in JavaScript like this one:

```
class Person {
    _firstName = "";
    _lastName = "";

    constructor(firstName, lastName) {
        this._firstName = firstName;
        this._lastName = lastName;
    }

    get firstName() {
        return this._firstName;
    }

    get lastName() {
        return this._lastName;
    }

    fullName() {
        return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
    }

}

let me = new Person("John", "Doe");
```

It creates a variable me that is an instance of  Person. Its prototype has some functions whose names are “fullName” and “get firstName” (plus other functions)

I can call the function fullName by its name using:

```
me[“fullName”]();
```

`John Doe`

However, calling the getter function by its name throws an error:

```
me[“get firstName”]();
```

`Uncaught TypeError: me.get firstName is not a function`

Why does this behavior happen?

EDIT: Thanks for the replies. I know I can and should access it as a property. But I'd like to understand why accessing it by its name with the brackets notation does not work. Does that mean JavaScript has different kinds of functions since a behavior that works for one function does not work for another function (when it has a space in its name / is a getter or setter)?

Comment: Access it as a property (which it actually becomes) `me['firstName']`. BTW if you know the name in advance as in your example you don't need to use bracket notation. Just do `me.firstName`

Comment: The name of the getter is not `get firstName`, but just `firstName`. The `get` part is a keyword, not related to the property name. You should of course leave out the parentheses, as a getter is accessed as a property, not as a function call.

Comment: @trincot using Chrome Dev Tools to watch the variable says that the name of the function is "get firstName"

Comment: See my answer for clarifying that last point, @user13671197

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a function is assigned to a variable or as a property value (maybe a getter), there are two names involved:

- The name of the function
- The name of the variable/property

These names are different entities and don't necessarily have to be the same.

Here is a simple object with property "a" that has as value a function whose name is "b":

```js
let obj = {
    a: function b() { }
};

console.log("property: ", Object.keys(obj)[0]); // "a"
console.log("function: ", obj.a.name); // "b"
```

Now when the function does not get an explicit name, it is given one:

```js
let obj = {
    a() { }
};

console.log("property: ", Object.keys(obj)[0]); // "a"
console.log("function: ", obj.a.name); // "a"
```

This may give the false impression that both names are one and the same string, but this cannot be true as the *same* function object might be assigned to *different* properties:

```js
let obj = {
    a() { }
};
obj.c = obj.a;

console.log("property: ", Object.keys(obj)[1]); // "c"
console.log("function: ", obj.c.name); // "a"
```

### Getters

The situation with a getter can be confusing, because the expression `obj.a.name` will not retrieve the name of the function, but will *invoke* the getter and then try to access the `name` property of the returned value.

To still get the name of the getter function, you can use `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor` as follows:

```js
let obj = {
    get a() { }
};

console.log("property: ", Object.keys(obj)[0]); // "a"
console.log("function: ", Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, "a").get.name); // "get a"
```

This is how a getter's function name is set by default. You can however set it explicitly to your desire using `Object.defineProperty` as follows:

```js
let obj = {};
Object.defineProperty(obj, "a", { 
    get: function b() {},
    enumerable: true 
});

console.log("property: ", Object.keys(obj)[0]); // "a"
console.log("function: ", Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, "a").get.name); // "b"
```

## Conclusions

- A *property* name does not necessarily match with the name of the *function* that might be the property's value.
- A property is identified by *property* name, not by the name of the function that might be associated with it.
- The function object, that serves as a getter property, can be accessed with `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(object, propertyName).get`

Comment: You might want to show an example with `Object.defineProperty(obj, "a", { get: function b() {} });`

Comment: thank you very much for the explanation and the code snippets!

Answer (score 1):

You should access it as a normal property like this:

```
me["firstName"];
```

But, if you know already the name, you could access the firstName value like this:

```
me.firstName
```

Typically, you use the first form if you want to access a property of an object using a variable like this:

```
const person = new Person("John", "Doe");
const propertyName = "firstName";
const firstName = person[propertyName];
```

*If you want to know more about getter and setters check out [this](https://javascript.info/property-accessors) and [this](https://javascript.info/property-accessors).*

Follows a fully working example:

```js
class Person {
    _firstName = "";
    _lastName = "";

    constructor(firstName, lastName) {
        this._firstName = firstName;
        this._lastName = lastName;
    }

    get firstName() {
        return this._firstName;
    }

    get lastName() {
        return this._lastName;
    }

    fullName() {
        return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
    }

}

const me = new Person("John", "Doe");
const propertyName = "firstName";
console.log(me["firstName"])
console.log(me.firstName)
console.log(me[propertyName])
```

Comment: Or even `me.firstname` for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

When doing this:

```
get firstName() {
    return this._firstName;
}
```

it´s defining a property and the you have to call it over:

```
me.firstName;
```

doing it like this:

```
getFirstName() {
    return this._firstName;
}
```

is really defining a getter function and you can call it like this:

```
me.getFirstName();
```

Maybe this is helpfull: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get